# Involution on variety lifts to vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. Let $i$ be an involution on $X$, which induces a $G=\mathbb{Z}\setminus (2)$ action on $X$.

Consider a vector bundle  $E$ on $X$. It is mentioned that $E$ has an $i$-action if there is a $G$-action on $E$ which lifts the $i$ action from $X$ to $E$. Then $E$ decomposes into $E^+\oplus E^-$, the Eigen bundles.

1) what exactly is the action on $E$? Is $E$ the locally free sheaf, or the space of sections?

2) what are the Eigen bundles? How do we get them?

3) are the Eigen bundles vector bundles or just torsion -free?

4) Do we have such a decomposition for any finite group action on a variety which lifts to $E$?

I will be grateful for any clarification. Thank you.

Comment: Is the claim that an involution of $X$ lifts to a vector bundle $E \to X$ _in general_ (which seems unlikely, offhand), or that a particular involution lifts to a particular vector bundle...?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang, you are right. I am modifying the question.

Comment: One more question: Does the stated decomposition really refer to $E$, or to the push-forward bundle $i_{*}E \to X/G$?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang, it is for the vector bundle $E$ on $X$.

Comment: For what it's worth, an involution $i$ of a vector space induces a canonical splitting into eigenspaces:
$$
v = \tfrac{1}{2}(v + i(v)) + \tfrac{1}{2}(v - i(v)).
$$
If $i$ is an involution of a vector bundle $E$ that fixes fibres (i.e., covers the identity map on the base), then $E$ splits canonically into eigenbundles. These are vector subbundles, not just torsion-free sheaves. If $i$ covers a non-trivial involution of the base, however, I don't know how to interpret the stated decomposition except as a decomposition of $i_{*}E \to X/G$.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang, I don't understand what you mean by $i$ covers the identity map on the base, and by non-trivial involution. Also can you post the details as answrr including the decomposition of $i_*E$ on the quotient? I will accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Item 1 may be obviated by the edit: The action on $E$ is *assumed* to exist. (In practice, the lift of $i$ to $E$ might be defined in a variety (no pun) of ways.) As for the remaining points:

If $f:X \to X$ is a map and $p:E \to X$ is a vector bundle, a vector bundle map $\tilde{f}:E \to E$ is said to *cover* $f$ if $p \circ \tilde{f} = f \circ p:E \to X$. (In words, $\tilde{f}$ maps the fibre $E_{x}$ over $x$ linearly to the fibre $E_{f(x)}$ over $f(x)$.)

Every involution of a vector space (finite-dimensional or not) induces a canonical splitting into eigenspaces:
$$
v = \tfrac{1}{2}(v + i(v)) + \tfrac{1}{2}(v - i(v)).
$$
(The summands are eigenvectors of $i$ with eigenvalue $1$ and $-1$, respectively.)

Applied fibrewise, if $i$ is an involution of a vector bundle $E$ that fixes fibres (i.e., covers the identity map on the base, so that $i$ induces an involution on each fibre of $E$), then $E$ splits canonically into eigenbundles. These are vector subbundles, not just torsion-free sheaves.

If $i:X \to X$ is an involution that lifts to $\tilde{\imath}:E \to E$, there is a push-forward vector bundle $i_{*}E \to X/G$ whose fibre at each point $[x] = \{x, i(x)\}$ in $X/G$ is $E_{x} \oplus E_{i(x)}$, the direct sum of the fibres of $E$ over the two preimage points of $[x]$. The involution $\tilde{\imath}:E \to E$ induces an involution of $i_{*}{E}$ that covers the identity on the quotient $X/G$, so $i_{*}E$ decomposes into $\pm1$-eigenbundles as above.

Explicitly, the involution of $i_{*}E$ sends $(v, w)$ to $(\tilde{\imath}(w), \tilde{\imath}(v))$. The respective eigenbundles comprise elements of the form $(v, \tilde{\imath}(v))$ of eigenvalue $1$, and $(v, -\tilde{\imath}(v))$ of eigenvalue $-1$.

If instead one wants to decompose $E \to X$, the issue is that $\tilde{\imath}:E_{x} \to E_{i(x)}$ isn't an involution of the fibres of $E$ individually, only an involution of the total space $E$.

Comment: one question,  if $i$ is an involution of the vector bundle which fixes the fibres, then $i(x,v)=(x,i_x(v))$, which is an involution, then the fiber splits into $\pm$ Eigen spaces. How do we define Eigen bundles. $E^+=(x,v)$, such that $v\in E_x^{+1}$ etc.?

Comment: Also why are the Eigen bundles vector bundles?

Comment: The splitting is that given by the "polarization" formulas $v_{\pm} = \frac{1}{2}(v \pm i(v))$. To see the eigenspaces (the kernels of the respective projections) have constant rank, note that the [rank of each is upper-semicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_sheaf#Local_behavior_of_coherent_sheaves), and the sum of their ranks is constant.

Comment: I have a question. Will a similar situation be valid for any finite group $G$?

Comment: If a (suitably well-behaved, e.g., free and properly-discontinuous) $G$-action on $X$ lifts to $E$, there is a push-forward vector bundle on $X/G$ whose fibre over $[x]$ is the direct sum of the fibres of $E$ over the points in the equivalence class of $x$. For an involution there's a "universal formula" for an eigenspace decomposition of $i_{*}E \to X/G$, but (in general) offhand I'm not sure about eigenbundles even over $\mathbf{C}$. Otherwise, I'd have included this detail in the original answer. ;)